# wordpress 3.5 tinymce height

Tags: tinymce, plugin-tinymce

I've just upgraded wordpress to 3.5 version and I noticed that TinyMCE Advanced Editor is not as tall as before.

How can I change default tinyMCE height?

**UPDATE**

This is the screenshot of section I want to render higher than the default

[image]

Answer (score 2):

@frabiacca:
I'm not sure if you meant the toolbar menu, like Circle B showed or the height of the writing place. If it's the latter you can :

- do it easily by gragging the bottom right corner or the textarea or clicking on the fullscreen button of the editor :D
- do it programmatically

[codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE](http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE)

```
function wptiny($initArray){
    $initArray['height'] = '600px';
    return $initArray;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'wptiny');
```

but this doesn't seem to work though it should

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor indicates that the settings array should contain `[  'editor_height' => 600 ]` to set the height, rather than `[ height => .... `

Answer (score 0):

To increase the height of the actual editing area of the WYSIWYG, add this code to the functions.php file:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'content_textarea_height');
function content_textarea_height() {
    echo'
    <style type="text/css">
            #content{ height:1000px !important; }
    </style>
    ';
}
```

To show all of the options in the tinyMCE you need to click the Kitchen Sink button:

[image]

Comment: I just edited my question by inserting a screeshot of section I want to make higher

Comment: I've updated the answer...

Comment: it does not work ... maybe because of qtranslate plugin?

Comment: That could be the case, can you inspect the element in FireBug or Chrome to see whether the style is even trying being applied?

Answer (score 0):

If the height of your editor has been changed after using **qtranslate plugin** (and only in this case), use the code below in your functions.php file :

```
// fix editor height problem with qtranslate
add_action('admin_head', 'content_textarea_height');
function content_textarea_height() {
    echo'
    <style type="text/css">
        #qtrans_textarea_content_ifr{ height:420px !important; }
    </style>
    ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add all the buttons shown on your screenshot you can set tiny beforehand by specializing the icons you want to see and where, take a look at the source of `wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php`

You may do something like this (reusing @user29296 proposed answer) by indicating the buttons you want on each lines of the header (i used only a few icons but you can add whatever you need on keys 1, 3 and 4 !! not 2 as it will not show...)

```
function wptiny($initArray)
{
    $initArray['editor_height'] = '360';
    $initArray['theme_advanced_buttons1'] = 'bold,italic,underline';
    // key 2 won't show, so not needed, hence we use wp_adv to show others by default
    $initArray['theme_advanced_buttons2'] = 'wp_adv';
    $initArray['theme_advanced_buttons3'] = 'justifycenter,justifyright';
    $initArray['theme_advanced_buttons4'] = 'link,unlink,undo,redo';
    return $initArray;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'wptiny');
```

In regards to the height of the editor(s), here is a more generic method that would respond to all needs no matter what id or class you apply (also works for an array of textareas)

```
function admin_custom_css()
{
    $data = '
        .wp-editor-container textarea.wp-editor-area,.mceIframeContainer iframe{
            min-height:360px !important;
        }
    ';
    $data = '<style type="text/css">'.$data.'</style>';

    echo $data;
}
add_action('admin_head', 'admin_custom_css' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my CSS and it worked for me.

```
iframe#name_of_iframe_id {min-height: 450px; !important;}
```